# Understanding results from Rubi integrator

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, rubi

I am just starting out with Mathematica and more specifically Rubi. I just tried to integrate the following.

```
In[5]:= r2 = r1^2 + t^2 d^2 + 2*r1*d*t*Cos[\[Theta]]
expr1 = (1 - R^2/r2)/((r1*(1 - R^2/r2))^2 + (d*(1 - t*R^2/r2))^2 + 
    2*r1*(1 - R^2/r2)*d*(1 - t*R^2/r2)*Cos[\[Theta]])

Out[5]= r1^2 + d^2 t^2 + 2 d r1 t Cos[\[Theta]]

Out[6]= (1 - R^2/(r1^2 + d^2 t^2 + 2 d r1 t Cos[\[Theta]]))/(
r1^2 (1 - R^2/(r1^2 + d^2 t^2 + 2 d r1 t Cos[\[Theta]]))^2 + 
 2 d r1 Cos[\[Theta]] (1 - R^2/(
    r1^2 + d^2 t^2 + 2 d r1 t Cos[\[Theta]])) (1 - (R^2 t)/(
    r1^2 + d^2 t^2 + 2 d r1 t Cos[\[Theta]])) + 
 d^2 (1 - (R^2 t)/(r1^2 + d^2 t^2 + 2 d r1 t Cos[\[Theta]]))^2)

In[9]:= Int[expr1, t]

Out[9]= t/(d^2 + r1^2 + 2 d r1 Cos[\[Theta]]) - 
 Removed["Int"][(
  R^2 (d^2 + R^2 - r1^2 - 2 d t (d + r1 Cos[\[Theta]])))/(
  R^4 + d^2 r1^2 - 2 R^2 r1^2 + r1^4 - 
   2 d r1 (R^2 - r1^2) Cos[\[Theta]] + 
   d^2 t^2 (d^2 + r1^2 + 2 d r1 Cos[\[Theta]]) - 
   2 d t (d R^2 - r1 (d^2 - R^2 + r1^2) Cos[\[Theta]] - 
      2 d r1^2 Cos[\[Theta]]^2)), t]/(
 d^2 + r1^2 + 2 d r1 Cos[\[Theta]])
```

I am a little confused by the Removed result. Does it seem to be some issue with installing the Paclet or am I misunderstanding the result.

I would also like to understand another solution that Rubi gives with respect to another integral. Putting it here since it falls broadly under the same question.

```
In[2]:= r12 = r2^2 + (d*(t - 1))^2 + 2*r2*d*(t - 1)*Cos[\[Theta]]

Out[2]= r2^2 + d^2 (-1 + t)^2 + 2 d r2 (-1 + t) Cos[\[Theta]]

In[3]:= expr1 = (1 - 
    R^2/r12)/((r2 (1 - R^2/r12))^2 + (d*(t - 1)*(R^2/r12))^2 + 
    2*(r2 (1 - R^2/r12))*d*(t - 1)*(R^2/r12)*Cos[\[Theta]])

Out[3]= (1 - R^2/(
 r2^2 + d^2 (-1 + t)^2 + 2 d r2 (-1 + t) Cos[\[Theta]]))/((
 d^2 R^4 (-1 + t)^2)/(r2^2 + d^2 (-1 + t)^2 + 
   2 d r2 (-1 + t) Cos[\[Theta]])^2 + (
 2 d R^2 r2 (-1 + t) Cos[\[Theta]] (1 - R^2/(
    r2^2 + d^2 (-1 + t)^2 + 2 d r2 (-1 + t) Cos[\[Theta]])))/(
 r2^2 + d^2 (-1 + t)^2 + 2 d r2 (-1 + t) Cos[\[Theta]]) + 
 r2^2 (1 - R^2/(
    r2^2 + d^2 (-1 + t)^2 + 2 d r2 (-1 + t) Cos[\[Theta]]))^2)

In[4]:= Int[expr1, {t, 0, 1}]

Out[4]= -
\!\(\*UnderscriptBox[\(\[Limit]\), \(t \[Rule] 0\)]\) (t/r2^2 - (
     R^2 Cos[\[Theta]] Log[
       r2^2 (R^2 - r2^2)^2 + d^4 r2^2 (-1 + t)^4 - 
        2 d r2 (R^2 - r2^2) (R^2 + 2 r2^2) (-1 + t) Cos[\[Theta]] + 
        2 d^3 r2 (R^2 + 2 r2^2) (-1 + t)^3 Cos[\[Theta]] + 
        d^2 (-1 + t)^2 (R^4 + 4 r2^4 + 
           2 r2^2 (R^2 + r2^2) Cos[2 \[Theta]])])/(2 d r2^3) - (
     R^2 (R^2 - r2^2) (R^2 + 
        4 r2^2 + (R^2 + 2 r2^2) Cos[2 \[Theta]]) Subst[
       Int[1/(r2^2 (R^2 - r2^2)^2 + d^4 r2^2 t^4 - 
         2 d r2 (R^2 - r2^2) (R^2 + 2 r2^2) t Cos[\[Theta]] + 
         2 d^3 r2 (R^2 + 2 r2^2) t^3 Cos[\[Theta]] + 
         d^2 t^2 (R^4 + 4 r2^4 + 
            2 r2^2 (R^2 + r2^2) Cos[2 \[Theta]])), t], t, -1 + t])/(
     2 r2^2) + (
     d R^2 Cos[\[Theta]] (R^4 + 2 R^2 r2^2 + 4 r2^4 + 
        2 r2^2 (R^2 + r2^2) Cos[2 \[Theta]]) Subst[
       Int[t/(r2^2 (R^2 - r2^2)^2 + d^4 r2^2 t^4 - 
         2 d r2 (R^2 - r2^2) (R^2 + 2 r2^2) t Cos[\[Theta]] + 
         2 d^3 r2 (R^2 + 2 r2^2) t^3 Cos[\[Theta]] + 
         d^2 t^2 (R^4 + 4 r2^4 + 
            2 r2^2 (R^2 + r2^2) Cos[2 \[Theta]])), t], t, -1 + t])/
     r2^3 + (d^2 R^2 (R^2 + 
        4 r2^2 + (3 R^2 + 2 r2^2) Cos[2 \[Theta]]) Subst[
       Int[t^2/(
        r2^2 (R^2 - r2^2)^2 + d^4 r2^2 t^4 - 
         2 d r2 (R^2 - r2^2) (R^2 + 2 r2^2) t Cos[\[Theta]] + 
         2 d^3 r2 (R^2 + 2 r2^2) t^3 Cos[\[Theta]] + 
         d^2 t^2 (R^4 + 4 r2^4 + 
            2 r2^2 (R^2 + r2^2) Cos[2 \[Theta]])), t], t, -1 + t])/(
     2 r2^2)) + 
\!\(\*UnderscriptBox[\(\[Limit]\), \(t \[Rule] 1\)]\) (t/r2^2 - (
    R^2 Cos[\[Theta]] Log[
      r2^2 (R^2 - r2^2)^2 + d^4 r2^2 (-1 + t)^4 - 
       2 d r2 (R^2 - r2^2) (R^2 + 2 r2^2) (-1 + t) Cos[\[Theta]] + 
       2 d^3 r2 (R^2 + 2 r2^2) (-1 + t)^3 Cos[\[Theta]] + 
       d^2 (-1 + t)^2 (R^4 + 4 r2^4 + 
          2 r2^2 (R^2 + r2^2) Cos[2 \[Theta]])])/(2 d r2^3) - (
    R^2 (R^2 - r2^2) (R^2 + 
       4 r2^2 + (R^2 + 2 r2^2) Cos[2 \[Theta]]) Subst[
      Int[1/(r2^2 (R^2 - r2^2)^2 + d^4 r2^2 t^4 - 
        2 d r2 (R^2 - r2^2) (R^2 + 2 r2^2) t Cos[\[Theta]] + 
        2 d^3 r2 (R^2 + 2 r2^2) t^3 Cos[\[Theta]] + 
        d^2 t^2 (R^4 + 4 r2^4 + 2 r2^2 (R^2 + r2^2) Cos[2 \[Theta]])),
        t], t, -1 + t])/(2 r2^2) + (
    d R^2 Cos[\[Theta]] (R^4 + 2 R^2 r2^2 + 4 r2^4 + 
       2 r2^2 (R^2 + r2^2) Cos[2 \[Theta]]) Subst[
      Int[t/(r2^2 (R^2 - r2^2)^2 + d^4 r2^2 t^4 - 
        2 d r2 (R^2 - r2^2) (R^2 + 2 r2^2) t Cos[\[Theta]] + 
        2 d^3 r2 (R^2 + 2 r2^2) t^3 Cos[\[Theta]] + 
        d^2 t^2 (R^4 + 4 r2^4 + 2 r2^2 (R^2 + r2^2) Cos[2 \[Theta]])),
        t], t, -1 + t])/r2^3 + (
    d^2 R^2 (R^2 + 4 r2^2 + (3 R^2 + 2 r2^2) Cos[2 \[Theta]]) Subst[
      Int[t^2/(
       r2^2 (R^2 - r2^2)^2 + d^4 r2^2 t^4 - 
        2 d r2 (R^2 - r2^2) (R^2 + 2 r2^2) t Cos[\[Theta]] + 
        2 d^3 r2 (R^2 + 2 r2^2) t^3 Cos[\[Theta]] + 
        d^2 t^2 (R^4 + 4 r2^4 + 2 r2^2 (R^2 + r2^2) Cos[2 \[Theta]])),
        t], t, -1 + t])/(2 r2^2))
```

I cannot find the function Subst in the Wolfram Documentation. Hence am a little confused if it is similar to Replace or does this have something do with improper loading of caches. I have tried quitting the kernel and starting it again and that does not have any effect.

Comment: I've seen this before many times. This could happen if you had used `Int` command earlier before loading Rubi` for an example or some other caching problem. When I see this, I always just restart with clean kernel, load `Rubi` again, and then try again. It should fix it. Screen shot  ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TUTv0.png)

Comment: Thanks a lot. You are correct. Tried it and it works. Pretty strange that it just does not show a error message or something. But thanks anyhow

Comment: In this regard is it possible to understand this result again from Rubi with a different integral. I am putting it here since it also falls under the same broad question.

Comment: Your second example is a valid output of Rubi. When the output has `Int` in it (with or without `Subst` behind it, it means Rubi has no rule for this integral and it could not solve it.   it could only solve part of it. btw, Rubi is meant to use for indefinite integrals. You can still use it for definite integrals like you did here, but be aware of what it says on this, in the middle of this page [rubi warning](https://rulebasedintegration.org/usingRubi.html)  btw, `Subst` is an internal Rubi command.

Comment: ....`A Rubi command of the form Int[expn,{var,a,b}] integrates expn with respect to var, and returns the limit of its antiderivative as var approaches b minus the limit as var approaches a. According to the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus (FTOC), this difference will equal the definite integral of expn from a to b if and only if the antiderivative is continuous between the two points.`  so it does not check if antiderivative is continuous. So sometimes it can give wrong result for definite integral. Unless you check yourself that FTOC was valid to use.